Using printf and calculation in zsh isn't working
I'm unable to do a calculation in zsh while having it formatted to the needed precision (2 decimal places).  I don't know if this is zsh-specific or would also occur in bash.  For example:
> Tmean=34.888
> SP=34.8
> ERR=$( printf "%.2f" $(( Tmean - SP )) )
> echo $ERR                               
0.0900000000

It's doing the proper rounding but leaving all the 0s. BUT:
> printf "%.2f" $ERR
0.09%

Why does it work only in a separate command?  Also, I don't know what that percent sign is doing there in the last output.

I can't reproduce

I also cannot reproduce; I get 0.09 either way (note: the "%" at the end of output from printf "%.2f" $ERR is zsh's way of indicating that the output did not end with a newline. Use printf "%.2f\n" $ERR (i.e. adding a newline to the end) to avoid this. BTW, in bash this'd cause an error because bash doesn't do floating-point arithmetic.

@KamilCuk and gordon-davisson, thank you for trying to reproduce and pointing out the source of the '%'.  I was experimenting with this on my Mac; when I tried it on the Debian server (TrueNAS) it worked.  Funny, both are using zsh 5.9. The options are similar and don't seem to be relevant. On the Mac they are combiningchars, correctall, histverify, interactive, monitor, sharehistory, shinstdin, zle.

What does typeset -p ERR say?

Just to be clear, it's on a Mac that this isn't working, but it is working on Debian?

Strangely, it seems to be working on the Mac now as well as the Debian server.  I'm not sure why.  Clearly I was in zsh on both machines, because the error is very different in bash. typeset -p ERR in both cases now gives typeset ERR=0.09.

In order to reproduce your steps, I need to declare ERR as a floating point variable first with typeset -F. That forces the output format:
% typeset -F ERR=0.09
% echo $ERR
0.0900000000

For 2 decimal places, you can just use typeset -F2 ERR so this is perhaps what you want:
typeset -F Tmean=34.888 SP=34.8
typeset -F2 ERR='Tmean - SP'

Internally this has preserved the full 0.088 value. You can remove that flag with typeset +F ERR to convert it to a scalar. If you want to use printf, you just want an ordinary scalar/string variable for the output. It doesn't affect the result here but given different input values, making Tmean and SP floating-point variables and avoiding the $(( ... )) form which converts them back to decimal string form will avoid losing precision:
% typeset -F Tmean=34.888 SP=34.8
% printf -v ERR '%.2f' 'Tmean - SP'
% typeset -p ERR
typeset ERR=0.09

As mentioned by others in comments, the extra % was due to the lack of a newline in your output. In a default setup, that should be printed in reverse. You can configure it to something that might stand out more for you, e.g.:
PROMPT_EOL_MARK=$'%K{3}\u2318%k'


To correct This, you can convert ERR to a floating-point number before formatting it. Here's how you can do it:
Tmean=34.888
SP=34.8
ERR=$(echo "scale=2; $Tmean - $SP" | bc)
ERR=$(printf "%.2f" $ERR)
echo $ERR

In your last output the % sign is because the $ERR is being treated as a string but the printf is requesting for a floating point number but not receiving a floating point number when it doesn't it outputs an error message and that is % symbol.
Hope it works. Have A Nice Day Buddy 

Thank you; that is helpful.  But I think bc is a bash thing; anyway I don't have it and can't put it on the NAS that's doing this (long story).  zsh does floating arithmetic out of the box, and using floating numbers in a calculation is supposed to result in a float.  But I'll look into first declaring ERR as a float and see if that fixes it.

@JimWorrall bc is a standard POSIX utility; it has nothing to do with what shell you're using.

Thanks @Shawn for the clarification.  In any case I can't install it on the TrueNAS server without violating the "appliance" concept, which other users of he script may not want to do.  That's why I'm using zsh, which does not rely on other utilities for float calculations.

This is nearly all wrong. As correctly stated in a comment on the Q, the % is because the printf output an unterminated line, and has nothing to do with floating-point, which zsh handles just fine by itself without bc.
